# ADC conversion rate

Tags: adc, soc, zynq

I have an ADC which is part of the Zynq-7000 SoC. For details please see the attached [datasheet](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf). I need to asses whether this ADC is appropriate for my application (measurement of stator currents in field oriented control of induction motor). Due to this reason I need to know the conversion time of the ADC. By inspecting of the datasheet I found that the ADC has conversion rate equal to 1 Msps. Does it mean that the conversion time is not longer than 1 us? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Page 2 says:  One million samples per second maximum conversion rate. Maximum might be the key word here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would imply that the conversion time is <1us.  If you need up to twice the sampling rate, page 20 suggests that both XADCs can be configured in a ping-pong configuration for up to 2Msps.